# Mocha,Chai test for backbone view

Tags: unit-testing, testing, backbone.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a backbone view which triggers a function who toggles active class across navigation bar. Can somebody please tell me how to test this toggling function? What should i use for that?How to run the test that it is actually working fine?

Comment: How to connect view and test file also?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to spy your function.

In your view you only need to trigger the action that calls your toggling function. Assuming that your function executes on click:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    this.spy = sinon.spy(yourMenuView, 'your function name');
    this.view = new Backbone.View(); //basic example
});

afterEach(function() {
   this.spy.restore();
   this.view.remove();
});

this.view.render();
this.view.$el.find('.selector').trigger('click');

expect(this.spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

It does not matter that your function happens, you only need to know it executes. The menu function should be testes in the Menu view.

I recommend you to read the Sinon documentation, is very helpful.